# XDocument : Difference between .Root.Value and .Root.ToString

Tags: c#

Does anybody know what is the difference between those two below statements :

```
xdoc.Root.Value;
```

and

```
xdoc.Root.ToString();
```

From my own research, I can see that the first line removes the root node and replaces the '\r\n' to '\n' whereas the second one keeps the content as original. Am I correct ? any documentation to back that up ?
As I want to use the first line but keep the original Windows new lines, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Just investigate a source code for differences, for example [XElement.Value](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,28102f706d70b3a2), because `XDocument.Root` is a `XElement` type

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation?

[`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A String that contains all of the text content of this element. If there are multiple text nodes, they will be concatenated.

[`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns the indented XML for this node.

Comment: Yes but they don't mention the carriage return removal

Comment: XML ignores newlines and other whitespace.

Comment: Well, it still keep the \n so it doesn't totally ignore newlines, right ?

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference is:
`ToString()` includes the root element tags and the indentation/tabs.
For example:
`<Root>
  <Child1>1</Child1>
</Root>`
Whereas, `value` doesn't; nor does it maintain the tabs, it just shows the content inside the root tag - it will show you the tags for the children, but not for the root itself:
For example:
`<Child1>1</Child1>`